# Creating a countdown timer with Javascript that can be started and stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am looking for assistance in creating a countdown timer inside a dialog box.

The logic will be as such:
1 - There is a datatable where a row is clickable (done)
2 - This opens a dialog that shows more information about the item (done)
3 - This item has an expiration date and I would like to show a countdown (attempted)

I am able to create a countdown timer and display it being counted down. However, when I close the dialog and click on another item, the countdown timer conflicts with the previously created countdown.

The function to create the countdown is as follows:

```
var countFunction = function countDownTimer(timeToCount) {
        var countDownDateTime = new Date(timeToCount).getTime();
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = "Timer has expired.";

        var timeLeft = countDownDateTime - now;

        if (timeLeft > 0) {
            const parts = {
                days: Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
                hours: Math.floor((timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
                minutes: Math.floor((timeLeft / 1000 / 60) % 60),
                seconds: Math.floor((timeLeft / 1000) % 60),
            };
            remaining = Object.keys(parts).map(part => {
                return `${parts[part]} ${part}`;
            }).join(" ");
            $('#P_CountDownTimer').text(remaining);
        }
        
    }
```

To call the function, within the script of opening the dialog, I use the following:

```
countDownTimer(cancellationDateTime);
setInterval(countDownTimer(cancellationDateTime), 1000);
```

Can anyone please guide me on how I can "destroy" the timer when I close the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to add one more condition to prevent remaining time to output while dialog is closed?

```js
if (dialogIsOpened && timeLeft > 0) {
  // ...
}
```